# time series with alternative ways of index

Tags: python, r, time-series, data-analysis

I am now processing time series like data which is in the following shape:

It has three columns say `t_1, t_2, att`. And `t_1` and `t_2` are ordered observations of time and `att` is numerical value.

Toy example of data:

```
    t_1           t_2        att
    12:30:32      12:33:12   1
    12:30:55      12:33:43   3
    12:31:21      12:34:34   2
```

The object I want to build is stick to the following rule:

1. If `t_1` is "continuous" then I build a time series object with `t_1`
   as time Index, `att` and `t_2` as value.
2. If `t_1` is not "continuous" and `t_2` is "continuous" then I build a
   time series object with `t_2` as time index, `t_1` and `att` as value
3. If `t_1` and `t_2` both not continuous, then report message back and
   build nothing
4. define interval< 1 hour, say, as continuous

An example of non-continuous `t_1` but continuous `t_2`:

```
    t_1           t_2        att
    12:30:32      12:33:12   1
    12:30:55      12:33:43   3
    14:31:21      12:34:34   2
    14:33:24      12:35:34   -12
```

Any ideas for implementation either in python or R will be super welcome. The data will be imported in as dataframe, either pandas dataframe or R dataframe.

Time series object like `xts` or `ts` in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, you can build `time series objects` from the tuples built from this:

```
import itertools as it
import datetime
data = [['12:30:32', '12:33:12', 1],
        ['12:30:55', '12:33:43', 3],
        ['14:31:21', '12:34:34', 2],
        ['14:33:24', '12:35:34', -12]]

def continuous(series, time_format = '%H:%M:%S', criteria = 3600):
    '''Returns True if time series is continuous.

    series -- sequence of strings
    time_format -- str (default '%H:%M:%S')
    criteria -- int (default 3600)
    '''
    # make datetime objects
    t = [datetime.datetime.strptime(thing, time_format) for thing in series]
    # find the deltas
    t2 = (two - one for one, two in it.izip(t, t[1:]))
    # apply the criteria
    return all(item.seconds <= criteria for item in t2)

# extract the time series data
one, two, values = zip(*data)
if continuous(one):
    # make tuples - (t1, (t2, att))
    time_series_data = [(t1, (t2, att)) for t1, t2, att in it.izip(one, two, values)]
elif continuous(two):
    # make tuples - (t2, (t1, att))
    time_series_data = [(t2, (t1, att)) for t1, t2, att in it.izip(one, two, values)]
else:
    raise ValueError('No Continuous Data')
```

Answer (score 0):

This makes a dictionary with the correct date as key and the other data as values:

```
from datetime import datetime

data = [['12:30:32', '12:33:12', 1],
        ['12:30:55', '12:33:43', 3],
        ['14:31:21', '12:34:34', 2],
        ['14:33:24', '12:35:34', -12]]


def test(ind):
    last = None
    for row in data:
        t = datetime.strptime(row[ind -1], '%H:%M:%S')
        if last and (t - last).seconds/3600. > 1:
            return False
        last = t
    return True

if test(1):
    obj = {row[0]:(row[1], row[2]) for row in data}
elif test(2):
    obj = {row[1]:(row[0], row[2]) for row in data}
else:
    print 'Error!'
```